# Can NAnt <tstamp> format day of the week as letters, like Java's SimpleDateFormat "E" pattern?

Tags: nant

I [searched SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nant+tstamp) and as far as I can tell, this hasn't already been asked.

I'd like to do this in NAnt:

```
<tstamp property="Now" pattern="EEE MMM dd, HH:mm"/>
```

in hopes of getting a result like: "Tue May 15, 09:05"

The [doc for NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/tstamp.html)  doesn't explicitly give a list of allowed pattern letters. I thought that it might work the way it does in [Ant](http://ant.apache.org), so I checked the [doc for Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tstamp.html)  which says:

> The date/time patterns are as defined in the Java [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class.

The SimpleDateFormat doc shows:

> E     Day in week     Text    Tuesday; Tue

Which is why I wrote my pattern (above) in NAnt. Unfortunately, the output I got is: "EEE May 6, 12:27", so it looks like E isn't supported.

My workaround is to examine `${datetime::get-day-of-week(datetime::now())}` and set my own dayofweektext property with a bunch of ifs, ala:

```
<if test="${datetime::get-day-of-week(datetime::now()) == '0'}">
    <property name = "dayofweektext" value = "Sun"/>
</if>
```

and then use this:

```
<tstamp property="Now" pattern="${dayofweektext} MMM dd, HH:mm" />
```

but all the ifs make for a lot of clutter.

**Is there a pattern that will do what I want?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me ...

```
<tstamp>
    <format property="build.date" pattern="E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"/>
</tstamp>
```

and produced...

```
build.date=Mon Mar 14 11:27:08 PDT 2011
```

Answer (score 1):

dddd MMM dd, HH:mm